Can cython detects if certain C header exists and compile conditionally?
I have a new C function in my library that doesn't exists in previous editions:
#define MYLIB_VERSION "dev"

const char *mylib_version(void) { return MYLIB_VERSION; }

Now, I can do this with my new Cython code:
cdef extern from "mylib.h":
    const char *mylib_get_version()

But this will fail if the system has my old library version instead.
The header "mylib.h" does not exists in my old version. Is there a way to conditional compile Cython code so I can write a fallback for older mylib versions?
I tried something weird to detect things on compile time. But it doesn't seem to work:
cdef extern from *:
    #if __has_include("mylib.h")
        #include "mylib.h"
        #define MYLIB_H_EXISTS 1
    #else
        #define MYLIB_H_EXISTS 0
    #endif

    IF MYLIB_H_EXISTS:
        cdef extern from "mylib.h":
            char *mylib_version()
    ELSE:
        cdef inline char *mylib_version():
            return "0.0.0"

Error:

Compile-time name 'MYLIB_H_EXISTS' not defined


I use make files to create/compile projects. Most of the make files contain the following lines at the beginning:
SHELL       = /usr/bin/env bash
DUMMY       := $(shell $(SHELL) ./setup.sh )
include Makefile.setup

So before doing any make job, bash script ./setup.sh is called. It analyses the environment (e.g. libraries) and write the result into Makefile.setup.

Any idea how to do this in meson?

https://mesonbuild.com/Compiler-properties.html#does-code-compile https://mesonbuild.com/Compiler-properties.html#does-a-header-exist

This seems to respond to a different question that was actually asked.  It's entirely possible that such an approach could help the OP, but if so, then this answer would be improved by editing it to describe how.
